# Pitfalls of IIS 7.5, thread agility and static variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have an application running in IIS (ASP.NET) and a significant amount of times, the page loads but rendered and populated with information for a user different than the user who actually requested the page. 
The data used to render and populate the page belongs to a user who also initiated a request at roughly the same point in time.

Could this be due to static variables and what I am now seeing referred to as thread agility?

Comment: That's a pretty vague description. How are you logging on a user to determine each user? What are you doing to retrieve the user's state? As to statics, they are AppDomain level which means that data is shared effectively globally in your ASP.NET application. if you're storing any user specific state on static's then data corruption is quite likely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't an issue with thread agility, it's an issue with using static variables. Static variables are static for the PROCESS, not one thread. So, a static variable in ASP.NET is shared by EVERY request being made to your site. So, ask yourself: is this static variable MEANT to be shared among every requester, or is it specific to ONE requester? For example:

```
static int TotalPageHits; //Count the number of times a page has been requested
```

Clearly, this is perfectly fine data to share for ALL users. On the other hand:

```
static string CurrentUserId; //DANGER WILL ROBINSON!!!!
```

Any variable specific to one requester you want to put in HttpContext.Current.Items.

Comment: I'm glad to know I'm not the only person who comments their code with the phrase "DANGER WILL ROBINSON."

Answer (score 1):

Static variables that contain user-specific data would explain the behavior you are seeing.

Thread agility might exascerbate the problem (e.g. make it more noticeable or lead to different manifestations of the problem, cause issues with [ThreadStatic](http://tao.qshine.com/note/ThreadIssue.html) usage, etc.), but I would start by examining your usage of static members.

```
// bad - any caller can access this in any sequence
public static int CurrentUserId
{
    get;
    set;
}

// okay, because the backing storage is safe/segmented
public static int CurrentUserId
{
    get { return (int)Session["CurrentUserId"]; }
    set { Session["CurrentUserId"] = value; }
}

// data that you want to be shared
public static List<string> SomeValuesToBeShared
{
    // safe for reading (if properly initialized) 
    // safe for writing only if appropriate locks are used
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF your code is really thread-safe this won't happen...

Use of static variables in such a context might a good starting point for investigation...

IF you mean anything marked `ThreadStatic` then this is a good starting point too...

To help in any specific way you need to provide much more details...